# Xlib: Create window in mimized or maximized state

Tags: c++, window, xlib, minimize, maximize

Is it possible to create a Window in maximized or minimized state with Xlib? If so, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure those are convenient window-manager fictions.  X doesn't know or care about them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this;

```
XEvent xev;
Atom wm_state  =  XInternAtom(dpy, "_NET_WM_STATE", False);
Atom max_horz  =  XInternAtom(dpy, "_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORZ", False);
Atom max_vert  =  XInternAtom(dpy, "_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT", False);

memset(&xev, 0, sizeof(xev));
xev.type = ClientMessage;
xev.xclient.window = win;
xev.xclient.message_type = wm_state;
xev.xclient.format = 32;
xev.xclient.data.l[0] = _NET_WM_STATE_ADD;
xev.xclient.data.l[1] = max_horz;
xev.xclient.data.l[2] = max_vert;

XSendEvent(dpy, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), False, SubstructureNotifyMask, &xev);
```

Comment: This works fine when the window is already mapped and managed. But is it possible to map the window in maximized state (i.e. avoid mapping in normal state and then transition to maximized state)?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [_NET_WM_STATE](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s05.html#id2522991) in the [EWMH](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/index.html).